# Svelte kit throws an error 'Unexpected option config.kit.prerender.default'

Tags: build, svelte

I'm new at Svelte, and I was trying to make a build of an application made with svelte.

I got this error message:

**error during build:
Error: Unexpected option config.kit.prerender.default**

and this is my svelte.config.js

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            pages: 'build',
            assets: 'build',
            fallback: 'index.html',
            precompress: false,
          }),
          prerender: {
            default: true,
          },
    },
    preprocess: vitePreprocess()
};

export default config;
```

I saw in the [docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapters), that I need to use an adapter, I would like to make a build for running on an nginx container, so I choose adapter static, but with the example in the docs it throws an exception, I looked up in google but I found nothing that works for me.

Another thing that I did is to write `export const prerender = true;` in every file in /src/routes

I saw the docs and put the same example and also put `export const prerender = true;` at the start of every file in /src/routes

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, I just did `git reset --hard`, I mean rolledback until my project didn't have any adapter, and then I updated my code like the docs says [adapter static](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static) doing that my svelte project did the build running `npm run build`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).